# Kentico 8.2 Settings App - Won't Load Sub nodes

Tags: kentico

I am trying to configure Versioning & Synchronization on a Kentico instance but I can't load the menu items.  I click on the expand icon and it just spins and doesn't open.

This only happens on our PROD environment and I think it might be related to SSL since that is the only difference between the environments. PROD uses SSL and the others aren't.

This doesn't happen with the Pages tree control.

Any suggestions for getting around this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is an issue with SSL and the web farm that caused the issue. If I point to just one of the servers via an ip address in my hosts file, I can get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a few things to help with this issue.

1. Check your event log in Kentico for errors.  Also look for errors specific to macro signatures.  If you have these errors and a lot of them, most likely your hash key (CMSHashStringSalt) in the web.config is different from your other environments.  If it is different you will have to resign your macros (System>Macros>Signatures).  Be sure to make sure the key listed above is the same across all environments.
2. Clear your browsers cache and do a CTRL + F5 to refresh the page.
3. Restart the application
4. Check the IIS event logs for errors.